# Al ejecutar mi función me sale el siguiente error: "dim(x) must have a positive length"

Tags: r, funciones

Buenas tengo el siguiente vector:

```
set.seed(1)
asu<-sample(c(1:100,NA), size = 500, replace = T)
```

Y deseo separar al vector por quintiles, es decir cuantos elementos se encuentran por cada quintil. Para lo cual realizo la siguiente función:

```
tablaza<-function(x){
  a<-quantile(x, probs = c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1), na.rm = T)
  a1<-sum(table(x[x<=a[1]]))
  a2<-sum(table(x[x>a[1] & x<=a[2]]))
  a3<-sum(table(x[x>a[2] & x<=a[3]]))
  a4<-sum(table(x[x>a[3] & x<=a[4]]))
  a5<-sum(table(x[x>a[4]]))
  tablaza<-matrix(c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5))
  tablaza
}
```

Posteriormente le aplico un **apply** para obtener los elementos del vector **asu** por quintil.

```
apply(asu, 2, tablaza)
```

En la cual me indica el siguiente error:

`Error in apply(asu, 2, tablaza) : dim(X) must have a positive length`

Que sepa apply soporta vectores. No sé en que estoy fallando quizá en la definición de la función.

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Comment: Comentario aparte: lo que buscas lo puedes resolver también de una manera más sencilla: `table(findInterval(asu,quantile(asu, probs = c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1), na.rm = T),left.open = TRUE))`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es una forma más abreviada de hacerlo. Para que pueda usarlo para varias columnas, lo tendría que hacer con un for? o lo defino como función y luego le aplico un apply?

Comment: Se puede usar cualquiera de las dos maneras que mencionas, en lo personal prefiero usar los bucles implícitos, por ejemplo `apply` ya que simplifican mucho el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, nuevamente!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eso sucede porque es un vector y no una matriz con filas y columnas, cuando usas `apply(a,b,c)` en el parametro `b` puede ser 1 para filas y 2 para columnas pero `asu` no es una matriz filas x columnas es un vector. Para aplicar la función que usted quiere usar solo debe usar `tablaza(asu)` o usar `apply(matrix(asu,500,1), 2, tablaza)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Excelente aporte!!!!.